# exception Handling In Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing a rest api using express JS . I want to show several error such as route not found, data not found, validation error. I am using async await structure . I need to know how to manage several exception handling in Express JS . I search seveal website but not found exact way . Everywhere write to use nodeJS default exception . But i need it customize in REST API.

**I need expert nodejs developer help . If anyone know best resource of express error handling please provide me link to learn this**

Comment: This question is far too broad.  Show us some code for typical things you want to protect against and we can recommend specific solutions.  The Express doc has a section on error handling.

Comment: Asking for outside resources here is considered off-topic.

Comment: Read https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html then try to adapt the examples to your requirements, and if you still have some specific question come back here for help

Comment: Refer this project and this file
https://github.com/sp-suresh/todoapiserver/blob/master/controllers/todo/todoHandler.js

Answer (score 0):

1.Let for handling route not found error you can use the default route

```
app.all('/*', (req, res)=> res.status(404).send('Route Not Found'))
```

2.For handling response, you can set some predefined response in separate module and send all response from that module. Like

```
    //response.js file
    module.exports= {
       ok : (res, data)=> res.status(200).send({data}),
       error: (res, err)=> res.status(err.status).send({error})
    }
```

3.For handling error you can make seperate error file where all error a set and create your error by those listed error. And you can do by try, catch

4.For validation, you can use middleware and or helper for handling validation.

5.Following are some node.js configuration link created by me, you can take reference from there

```
https://github.com/bapinmalakar/election-exitpoll-back (very simple, Github)
https://github.com/bapinmalakar/pt-backend (little complex, github)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can log the error using middleware As below given example middleware we can catch the errors which are thrown across the application. Also, we can catch the promise rejections

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(err.statusCode || 500).send(err);
        console.error(err.stack);
        next();
    }

    console.error(`Message :: ${err.message}
                   Url :: ${req.originalUrl}
                   Method :: ${req.method}
                   Ip :: ${req.ip}
                   Time :: ${(new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()}`);
});
```

For reference use this link. [Click here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)